# Page_Load after Modal Popup

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have a page with a user control which gets some data updated via a modal popup. Upon clicking "ok" on the modal popup - the new data is being written to the database - but the base page doesnt "reload" to show the updated data.  How do I get that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't set the OKControlID property on the ModalPopupExtender.
2) In your Page_Load, set `OkButton.OnClientClick = string.Format("$find('{0}').hide();", modalPopupExtender1.ClientID);`

Explanation:
Setting the OkControlID stops the button from posting back. Instead, manually use javascript to hide the extender, which will allow the button to post the form.

Comment: Also look for the "OKControlID"

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to update that control using ajax, or you could just do a Response.Redirect(assuming your modal is .net, or document.location if js) back to your page after your data has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Ok" button in your modal popup is causing a postback. If you want it to be ajax-enabled, make sure to put it inside of an update panel.